# Minor CSS issue in the vote-to-close window

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, css

If I click the "close (x)" link on a question that I have previously voted to close, I am present with a window similar to what is seen when I first clicked the link. The biggest difference is that the radio buttons are gone (wouldn't make sense to select a reason, anyway), and the "Vote to Close" button doesn't do anything.

However, the cursor still appears as a pointer over anything that *would be* clickable if I were able to cast a vote.

[This is where I was going to put the screenshot, but looking at it reminded me that the cursor does not show up in screenshots]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build (after rev 2012.5.9.2511).